# AWS Service Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created case for increasing service rate limit of aws lambda for handling heavy load in our application. I want to get information about whether aws take any charges monthly/one time for increasing limit?

Answer (score 3):

There is **no charge to process your request** to increase the limit. See: [AWS Lambda Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) for the actual cost over free tier.

- **Free Tier** - 1M REQUESTS per month / 400 GB-SECONDS of compute time per month.
- **Requests** - 1M REQUESTS FREE First 1M requests per month are free. / $0.20 PER 1M REQUESTS THEREAFTER $0.0000002 per request.
- **Duration** - 400,000 GB-SECONDS PER MONTH FREE / First 400,000 GB-seconds per month, up to 3.2M seconds of compute time, are free. $0.00001667 FOR EVERY GB-SECOND USED THEREAFTER

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @hellov have written.

You can control code execution performance and costs for your Lambda function by adjusting `Memory` and `Timeout`.
These are present in Basic Setting of your Lambda function console. However these will affect your pricing. Please visit [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) for more detailed information regarding the pricing.

Below is a complex example how the pricing will work:

> Let’s assume you have three functions, each with different memory
>   sizes as described below:
>
> **Function 1**
>
> 128MB of memory, executed 25M times in one month, runs for 200ms each
>   time
>
> Total compute (seconds) = 25M * (0.2sec) = 5M seconds
>
> **Function 2**
>
> 448MB of memory, executed 5M times in one month, runs for 500ms each
>   time
>
> Total compute (seconds) = 5M * (0.5sec) = 2M seconds
>
> **Function 3**
>
> 1024MB of memory, executed 2.5M times in one month, runs for 1 second
>   each time
>
> Total compute (seconds) = 2.5M * (1sec) = 2.5M seconds
>
> If you ran these functions, your charges would be calculated as
>   follows:
>
> **Monthly compute charges**
>
> AWS Lambda normalizes the total compute time to GB-s and then sums the
>   total across all functions
>
> Function 1 (GB-S) = 5M seconds * (128MB/1024) = 625,000 GB-s
>
> Function 2 (GB-S) = 2.5M seconds * (448MB/1024) = 1,093,750 GB-s
>
> Function 3 (GB-S) = 2.5M seconds * (1024MB/1024) = 2,500,000 GB-s
>
> Total monthly compute usage (GB-S) = 4,218,750 GB-s
>
> The monthly compute price is $0.00001667 per GB-s and the free tier
>   provides 400,000 GB-s. Monthly charged compute usage = Total monthly
>   compute usage – Free tier usage
>
> Monthly charged compute usage = 4,218,750 – 400,000 = 3,818,750 GB-s
>
> Monthly compute charges = 3,818,750 * 0.00001667 = $63.66
>
> **Monthly request charges**
>
> The monthly request price is $0.20 per 1 million requests and the free
>   tier provides 1M requests per month.
>
> Total requests – Free tier requests = Monthly billable requests
>
> (25M+5M+2.5M) requests – 1M free tier requests = 31.5M Monthly
>   billable requests
>
> Monthly request charges = 31.5M * $0.2/M = $6.30
>
> **Total Monthly Charges**
>
> Total charges = Compute charges + Request charges = $63.66 + $6.30 =
>   $69.96 per month